# Push to array recursively to build a tree

Tags: javascript, tree

I'm trying to traverse through some JSON that is coming from an API call, and restructure it to build a tree that is better formatted for the intended use.

Here's an example of the JSON from the API call:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1, "name": "Top Node 1", "children": {
        "value": [{
            "id": 11, "name": "Second Node 1", "children": {
                "value": [{
                    "id": 112, "children": null, "name": "Third Node 1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 112, "children": null, "name": "Third Node 2",
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 13, "name": "Second Node 3", "children": {
                "value": [{
                    "id": 131, "name": "Third Node 3", "children": {
                        "value": [{
                            "id": 1311, "name": "Fourth Node 2", "children": null
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
},
{
    "id": 2, "name": "Top Node 2", "children": null,
}]
```

Here's the desired outcome:

```
var data = [{
    "treename": "Top Node 1", "treeid": 1, "collapsed": false, "children": [{
        "treename": "Second Node 1", "treeid": 11, "collapsed": false, "children": [{
            "treename": "Third Node 1", "treeid": 111, "collapsed": false, "children": []
        },
        {
            "treename": "Third Node 2", "treeid": 112, "collapsed": false, "children": []
        },
        {
            "treename": "Delete", "treeid": "source113", "collapsed": false, "children": []
        }]
    }]
}]; // and so on and so on...
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var buildTree = function(obj){
    console.log(traverse(obj, []));
}

var traverse = function(obj, arr){
    obj.forEach((v, k) => {
        arr.push({ children: v.children != null ? traverse(v.children.value, []) : [], treename: v.name, treeid: v.id, collapsed: false });
    });
}

buildTree(data);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bob_sacamano/hktfub3z/)

My approach seems to be wrong, because the array keeps being overwritten. Any ideas on how to do this properly would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the new objects and check if childrens are available. Then map the children as well.

```js
function map({ name: treename, id: treeid, collapsed = false, children }) {
    return {
        treename,
        treeid,
        collapsed,
        children: (children && children.value || []).map(map)
    };
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Top Node 1", children: { value: [{ id: 11, name: "Second Node 1", children: { value: [{ id: 112, children: null, name: "Third Node 1" }, { id: 112, children: null, name: "Third Node 2" }] } }, { id: 13, name: "Second Node 3", children: { value: [{ id: 131, name: "Third Node 3", children: { value: [{ id: 1311, name: "Fourth Node 2", children: null }] } }] } }] } }, { id: 2, name: "Top Node 2", children: null }],
    result = data.map(map);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
function map(o) {
    return {
        treename: o.name,
        treeid: o.id,
        collapsed: false,
        children: (o.children && o.children.value || []).map(map)
    };
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Top Node 1", children: { value: [{ id: 11, name: "Second Node 1", children: { value: [{ id: 112, children: null, name: "Third Node 1" }, { id: 112, children: null, name: "Third Node 2" }] } }, { id: 13, name: "Second Node 3", children: { value: [{ id: 131, name: "Third Node 3", children: { value: [{ id: 1311, name: "Fourth Node 2", children: null }] } }] } }] } }, { id: 2, name: "Top Node 2", children: null }],
    result = data.map(map);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the role of the `collapsed` ,....anyway You could try the following one:

```
function t(elems, acc) {
    acc = acc  || [];
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        acc.push({
            treename: elem.name,
            treeid: elem.id,
            collapsed: false,
            children : (elem.children && elem.children.value) ? t(elem.children.value) : null
        });
    });
    return acc;
}
//then call it just passing your data as first param, the second is an accumulation var
var transformed = t(data);
console.log(transformed)
```

hope it helps.